# Bluetooth from commandline?

Tags: firefox, internet

I've been trying to pair up my bluetooth keyboard with my computer after reinstalling from a standard ubuntu 12.04 to a minimal install.

In the minimal install I have no gui, so I've been trying to use the various command line tools available, but I can't figure out how the pairing is supposed to go. Pairing when I had a gui worked flawlessly.

I've asked for help here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12234695

No one has replied but a lot of details of my situation is available there.

How is one supposed to pair bluetooth devices from the command line?

Comment: See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingInternetExplorer).

Comment: IE is dead, long live IE. I don't see why would you want to use a non native browser for daily browsing.

Comment: You can use Chrome rather than Firefox if you want...

Comment: Any specific reason for why you really want to use Internet Explorer to browse the Internet? First of all, it's heavily integrated into Windows and it's not available for Linux/Ubuntu in a sane way. It would require Windows emulation like Wine/PlayOnLinux will do for you. This is very inefficient and should only be used for development/testing etc. and I would recommend to use a supported browser like Firefox/Chrome/Konqueror to browse the web for daily use. Perhaps it would be a good idea to ask a question to get to the functionality you would like to see in Ubuntu of IE.

Comment: Why did you edit your question to something entirely different? If you want to ask a new question, just do it [the same way](/questions/ask) you asked this one.

Comment: We're very sorry, but this is not a good place to put another question as the only people seeing your "question" will be a bunch of reviewers trying to review your "question" for quality...  So please first look over the existing answers already here and if none of them work, [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)...  Please?  **;-)**

Answer (score 4):

While you *technically can* use Wine or VirtualBox one has you running in a broken and probably vulnerable state and the other has you running a full-blown copy or Windows.

You might not be able to see the technical issues with those but as somebody who can, I'm *begging* you: **don't do these!**

---

The direct everyday answer to the question is: **No, you can't install Internet Explorer** [in a native, good performing, non-buggy and *safe* way]. Microsoft never made a version of Internet Explorer for Linux. That's the problem and that's certainly one reason it's not in the Ubuntu App Store.

The best outcome here is getting used to another browser. I sympathise that change is hard (we all went through it when we moved to Ubuntu) but in this case, it's sincerely worth it. IE was technically —again— rubbish and MS are killing it off the brand in newer versions of Windows.

Both Firefox and Chrome are heavily customisable. If there's a particular behaviour you're missing, there's probably a plugin for it:

- [Firefox Add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/)
- [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps)

Comment: +1 @GrantSeltzerRichman I agree wine/POL are a pain and is no substitute for a native program, so here is a list of all linux browsers there are loads to choose from and any withe the "UI toolkit" option GTK will work great on Ubuntu http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers_for_Unix_and_Unix-like_operating_systems

Answer (score 1):

The program is a single vulnerability. You should think about you, whether that's really necessary. **My recommendation is a definite NO.**

---

First install PlayOnLinux:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Then select "Internet Explorer" and install.

[image]